# I am trying to get the mode of an input of ten numbers in java

Tags: java, oop, loops

```
import java.util.*;
public class main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] quiz = new int[10];
        int mean = 0,mode = 0,median,range;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int x=0;x<=9;x++){
            System.out.print("Enter quiz["+(x+1)+"]:");
            quiz[x]= scan.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(quiz);
        for(int x=0;x<=9;x++){
            mean = mean+quiz[x];
        }
        mean = mean/10;
        median = (quiz[4]+quiz[5])/2;
        range = quiz[9]-quiz[0];
        int[] cntr = new int[10];
            for(int x=0;x<=9;x++){
                for(int y=0;y<=9;y++){
                    if (quiz[x]==quiz[y]&&x!=y){
                        cntr[x]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        int[] sortcntr = cntr;
        int ndx = 0;
        Arrays.sort(sortcntr);
        for(int z=0;z<=9;z++){
            if(cntr[z]==sortcntr[9]){
                ndx = z;
            }
            else 
                mode=0;
        }
        mode = quiz[ndx];
        System.out.println("Mean: "+mean);
        System.out.println("Median: "+median);
        System.out.println("Range: "+range);
        if(mode==0){
        System.out.println("Mode: none");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Mode: "+mode);
        System.out.print(sortcntr[9]);
        System.out.print(cntr[9]);
        System.out.println(ndx);
    }

}
```

this is the codes that i used everything is right except for the mode. the mode variable there always returns the highest number from the number. the latter part was just for debugging and not for use. please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would have helped if you had mentioned that the code is about computing statistical figures from a few samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem of your code is that you obviously think that the line

```
int[] sortcntr = cntr;
```

creates a copy of the array *cntr*. However, arrays have reference semantics in Java. Thus, you simply create a second reference to the same array. If you then sort *sortcntr*, it applies to *cntr* as well since it's the same array.

To create a copy of the array:

```
int[] sortcntr = new int[ cntr.length ];
System.arraycopy(cntr, 0, sortcntr, 0, cntr.length);
```

BTW: Wouldn't it make more sense to work with floating-point numbers (*double*) instead of integer numbers?

Comment: i was thinking of that already but dont know any other way to copy that elements of that array i didnt think double is necessary because the input are just whole numbers. the program is just an exercise though

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(int x=0;x<=9;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<=9;y++){
```

The inner loop should start at x+1, otherwise you count everything twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since the input is already sorted to compute range and median, you can use the following code to get the mode after a single loop and without any extra memory (live on [ideone](http://ideone.com/CcSuak)):

```
// this must be sorted
int[] values = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8};

int mode = values[0];
int modeOccurrences = 1;

int occurrences = 1;
int current = values[0];

for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    int value = values[i];
    if (value == current) {
        occurrences++;
    } else {

        if (occurrences > modeOccurrences) {
            mode = current;
            modeOccurrences = occurrences;
        }

        occurrences = 1;
        current = value;
    }
}

if (occurrences > modeOccurrences) {
    mode = current;
    modeOccurrences = occurrences;
}
```

You can even [generify this piece of code](http://ideone.com/Uxv61v) to work with plain objects instead of numerical types, provided modes can be sorted and compared (I used enums in my demo)

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you out, if you decide to more generify (As Raffaele said) the process of getting the mode of a given set of data, here is a method I developed a while ago which will even return multiple modes if there are more than one with the same occurrence. (Uses the Java 8 Stream API)

```
/**
 * Computes the mode of the passed integers.
 *
 * @param args Numbers to find the mode of.
 * @return Mode of the passed numbers.
 */
public static int[] mode(int... args) {
    /* Create a map of integers to their frequencies */
    Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = IntStream.of(args).collect(
            HashMap::new,//Indicated that this collector will result in a HashMap
            (integerIntegerMap, value) -> integerIntegerMap.merge(value, 1, Maths::sum), //For each value in the arguments added, merge it with the current map and add the frequencies
            (integerIntegerMap, integerIntegerMap2) -> integerIntegerMap.putAll(integerIntegerMap2) //While this is not used, it simply combines 2 HashMaps. (I think this is only used when in parallel)
    );
    //Here we get the maximum number of occurrences for any number, we could return the mode here; but there could be multiple modes
    int maxOccurrences = frequencies.entrySet().stream().mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue).max().getAsInt();
    //Here we simply go through the entry set again, filtering out only the numbers with a frequency equal to the max, then returning them as an array
    return frequencies.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == maxOccurrences).mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey).toArray();
}
```

*-Thomas*